# ¿Cómo subir jsp a firebase?

Tags: firebase, jsp

Buenas tardes. Estoy subiendo mí proyecto al host de firebase pero únicamente me acepta los .html, ¿de qué manera puedo subir y que me acepte correctamente los .jsp?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: No se puede. Firebase es solo para archivos estáticos. Para los jsp debe ser un servidor de aplicaciones java.

Comment: @Lobos Ok, muchas gracias.